# OS X / Cocoa - how to read in every file from a directory?

Tags: cocoa, macos

What's the "right way" to read in every file from a directory on OS X using Cocoa?  I need to get the filename of each file and then I need to pull it's contents in to one NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSDirectoryEnumerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/)
and
[File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Get an enumerator for the path in question using the NSFileManager:

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator* enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:path];
```

Then call nextObject on the enumerator in a loop until it returns nil.